# paypal sandbox integration API credentials not found

Tags: java, paypal, integration, paypal-sandbox

am trying to integrate paypal sandbox with my web application.

For that as per the documentation I had created an account in `https://developer.paypal.com/`.
And after that I had created a Test Account also - that's a Business account.
I had created that account by selecting the seller radio button in the below mentioned screen.

[image: Test Account User creation Screen]

now when am clicking on my `Test Accounts` link, I can found a Business Test Account there as in the below mentioned figure.

[image: Showing Business User Test Account]

After that when am trying to get the API Credentials by clicking on the link `API and Payment Card Credentials` , its saying `my test account do not have credentials and create a business Test Account to get the credentials`. See image below.

[image: Error showing Account is not having API Credentials]

Actually I have created was a Business Test Account. Then why am not getting the API Credentials.Can anyone help me solve this.?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally solved it. You have to click 'Preconfigured' in your second screenshot when creating the seller account, otherwise any created accounts won't have the API details.