# PayPal Sandbox API Credentials for DoDirectPay

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to setup a testbed in PayPal Sandbox in order to implement/test the DoDirectPay API for my company.  DoDirectPay uses a certificate file (as opposed to a signature) per the documentation as well as the example code snippet [here](https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-dodirectpayment-php-5.3/soap)

Per the top Google search [result](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/apicertificates) for "download api certificate paypal" it should be possible to choose between obtaining a signature or downloading a certificate.

The test Merchant account I have created for sandbox was instantiated properly; and I am able to login to the sandbox site without issue.  I have verified that the Merchant account is indeed set up for PayPal Pro.  When I proceed to Account->Profile->Request API Credentials the only option is to obtain a signature.  The signature matches what is displayed in the Sandbox admin panel for users; however that is useless to me as I need to test DoDirectPay which requires a PEM formatted certificate file.

How can I get SandBox to spit out a certificate file for me to test DoDirectPay API?

P.S. - I have already looked through several articles including [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769876/paypal-api-credentials-for-sandbox) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628631/paypal-sandbox-integration-api-credentials-not-found) but neither really seems to relate to exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must first remove the API signature before you can request an API certificate.

1. Log in to Developer.paypal.com
2. Choose the account you would like to request a certificate for, then click "Sandbox Site"
3. Log in to your Sandbox account
4. Click "Profile" at the top of the page
5. Click "Request API Credentials"
6. Click "set up PayPal API credentials and permissions"
7. Click "View API Signature"
8. Click "Remove"
9. Click "Request API Credentials"
10. Choose Request API Certificate, then click "Agree and Submit"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Currently at the time of writing, the procedure mentioned doesn't works, an error with message 5010 shows up. Therefore it's not possible request test certificates unless PayPal fixes the error.

Answer (score -1):

In reference to the original question, paypal allows dodirectpayment api calls with an API signature too. you do not need  a certificate.